# How to view the default listing that comes with Drupal (teasers) of all articles in a node type?

Tags: drupal, cck, voting, drupal-fivestar

I'm always using views and more complicated things for Drupal but it seems that I don't know the basics.

I need to display all the articles in a node type without views...
(I'm using the Five Star voting and in the views I can't add it in fields..it doesn't appear in the list )

but it does appear in the teaser listing..

I just don't know how to access that!

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Views. You just need to change your view from the default Style: Table to Style: Unformatted or Style: List. Then change Row Style: to Node, and click on the settings icon to choose the Teaser build mode.

Comment: ok thanks for the info.. I finally done it with views and PHP customfield by embeding the form of the 5 star for the corespondent node and some queries for the counts and so..